# What is the difference between openwrt and μTenux？

Tags: openwrt, system-on-chip

I am a new commer in SOC, I have a question about two systems, 
*OpenWRT* and *μTenux*.

It seems both solutions can work, but what is the difference between each?

When should we use *OpenWRT* for the basis of a new application?  When should we use *μTenux*?

I want to write a SOC application, which can make socket connection to website and fetch a config file. Which system should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

OpenWrt is a Linux based OS tailored towards router software, i.e. it has web front-end for configuring various network parameters. It is more suitable for server side.

μTenux seems to be bare metal real-time OS, i.e. not Linux based. It is capable of fetching a config file via web.

If you just want to write a client application I would recommend [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/).